# Adding Tags to MailChimp Member object

Tags: c#, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm using MailChimp.Net.V3 (version 4 of this package) by Brandon Seydel. I'm trying to add a Tag a Member using the following code

```
using MailChimp.Net;

private async Task MaintainTagsAsync()
{
    string apikey = "<apikey>";
    string listid = "<listid>";
    string emailaddress = "x@x.com";

    try {
      MailChimpManager Mcm = new MailChimpManager(apikey);
      Member m = await Mcm.Members.GetAsync(listid, emailaddress);
      m.Tags.Add(new MemberTag
      {
        Name = "MyTag"
      });
      m.TagsCount = +1;
      await Mcm.Members.AddOrUpdateAsync(listid, m);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

The above code appears to execute OK but when I inspect the Member, I find that the Tag has not been added. I've tried it with and without incrementing the TagsCount property with the same result.

Does anyone have any experience of using this functionality and can throw any light on where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Why do you think it's do to `async-await`?

Comment: Well, as the process uses asynchronous processing there's a possibility that my implementation of the asynchronous code may cause the code not to work as expected.

Comment: The only asynchronous code in there is `await Mcm.Members.AddOrUpdateAsync(listid, m)`. Your problem seems to be before that. Isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're helping. There are actually 2 awaits in the routine if you look closely. I don't think the problem is to do with async but I added the tag just in case anyone else thought it might be.

Comment: You get `m` from an awaited call. From there until the next `await` the code is synchronous. Have you looked into the source code of the MailChimp API?

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {}` hides any errors that would help you understand what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now found a method which appears to work. Please see the following code:

```
using MailChimp.Net;

private async Task MaintainTagsAsync()
{
    string apikey = "<apikey>";
    string listid = "<listid>";
    string emailaddress = "x@x.com";

    try {
      MailChimpManager Mcm = new MailChimpManager(apikey);
      Member m = await Mcm.Members.GetAsync(listid, emailaddress);
      Tags tags = new Tags();
      tags.MemberTags.Add(new Tag() {
            Name = "MyTag",
            Status = "active"
      });
      await Mcm.Members.AddTagsAsync(listId, emailaddress, tags);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I am still using the Segment API and MailChimp says it is still supported, last time I asked. "Tags" are essentially the same thing and you can easily add or remove a member from a List Segment with the current version of the API.